# openssl on Ubuntu - no zlib

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

on my Debian machines when I enter openssl -V I see the zlib algorithm.

On Ubuntu I do not have zlib support for openssl, so the SSH also not support zlib.

Why is this?

I tried several thing to get zlib support on Ubuntu for SSH but I failed.

Can anyone helpo me?

King Regards

Comment: What have you tried? You should just be able to add `Compression delayed` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: I tried "Compression yes" but openssl -V does not show zlib in the list.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH links dynamically to zlib. You can see this by running `ldd /usr/bin/ssh` and looking for the libz.so.1 reference. The fact that OpenSSL does not show zlib does not mean that OpenSSH cannot use zlib.

Comment: ok, thanks but when I try to connect with my client I always get this error "negotiation failed" - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/howto-resolve-algorithm-negotiation-failed-issue-on-ssh

Does this mean that the compression via SSH does not work properly?